# Forbidden: Request forbidden -- authorization will not help ([GET] https://api.anaconda.org/user -> 403)

Tags: python, anaconda

When I open the anaconda navigator, it gives me the following error. The URL in which this error comes is `file:///C:/Users/Heaper/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpmdsmzme5.html`.

Strangely, I could open anaconda navigator yesterday, then today, after I turned on my laptop and clicked on anaconda navigator, this error showed up.

The error:

```
Navigator Error

An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up

Report

Please report this issue in the anaconda issue tracker

Main Error

('Forbidden: Request forbidden -- authorization will not help ([GET] https://api.anaconda.org/user -> 403)', 403)

Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 72, in exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  
File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 146, in start_app
    window = run_app(splash)
  
File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 65, in run_app
    window = MainWindow(splash=splash)

File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.api = AnacondaAPI()

File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 1518, in AnacondaAPI
    ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()

File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 83, in __init__
    self._client_api = ClientAPI(config=self.config)

File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 659, in ClientAPI
    CLIENT_API = _ClientAPI(config=config)

File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.reload_client()

File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 326, in reload_client
    client.user()

File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 245, in user
    self._check_response(res)

File "C:\Users\Heaper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 230, in _check_response
    raise ErrCls(msg, res.status_code)
binstar_client.errors.BinstarError: ('Forbidden: Request forbidden -- authorization will not help ([GET] https://api.anaconda.org/user -> 403)', 403)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of sites and repositories are experiencing outages because of Let's Encrypt root certificate expiration. Things will eventually come back to normal in a few days: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured when your internet connection is filtered or partially blocked. For example some of companies blocks some of websites on their wi-fi. If you change your connection and try to run anaconda it will be fixed.